# Recursion tree when level sum is same

Tags: algorithm, recursion, big-o, recurrence

I've been trying to solve questions using recurrence tree method and usually we can find level sums and get a GP where we can then apply the infinite GP sum and therefore get the final Big-O value of it.

What do we do for cases that have the same level sum such as -

T(n) = 3T(n/3) + cn

The answer for the following is Theta(nlogn)

Answer (score 0):

First, let T(1)=1, n=3^k and c=1:

```
  T(n)   = 3T(n/3) + cn
= T(3^k) = 3T(3^(k-1)) + 3^k
         = 3(3T(3^(k-2)) + 3^(k-1)) + 3^k
         = 3^2T(3^(k-2)) + 3^k + 3^k
         = 3^2(3T(3^(k-3)) + 3^(k-2)) + 3^k + 3^k
         = 3^3T(3^(k-3)) + 3^k + 3^k + 3^k
         = ...
         = 3^kT(1) + k*3^k 
         = nT(1) + n*log3n
         = n + n*log3n
```

Can you prove by induction from here?

@Edit

Consider de following tree expansion:

```
                    n                     = n
    n/3            n/3            n/3     = n
n/9 n/9 n/9    n/9 n/9 n/9    n/9 n/9 n/9 = n
                   ...                    = n
```

Each row sums up to n. If you assume n=3^k, the tree is balanced and has k=log3n height, hence the complexity is Theta(n*log3n).

Comment: Thanks a lot, it clarifies it quite a lot, but how do I do it using the recursion tree method with the levels and branches ?